# How to match spaces that are NOT in a multiple of 4?

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I'm re-formatting a Python script using notepad++, but some lines are not indented by 4 (or 8, 12, 16, etc.) spaces.

So I need to **match consecutive leading white-spaces** (i.e. indentation at beginning of each line), which are **NOT in multiple of 4**, i.e. spaces in number of 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, etc.

e.g.

```
>>>   a = 1      # match this, as there're 3 spaces at the beginning
>>>       b = a  # match this too, as indent by 7 spaces
>>>    c = 2     # but not this, since it's indented exactly by 4 spaces
>>>        d = c # not this either, since indented by 8 spaces
```

I was able to match spaces in multiple of 4 using something like:

```
^( {16}| {12}| {8}| {4})
```

then I tried to match the opposite of this with something like:

```
^[^( {16}| {12}| {8}| {4})]
```

but it only matches empty line or line start with a character, not what I want.

I'm a complete newbie to regex, but I've searched for hours with no luck. I know I could always match with all the non-multiple-of-4 numbers listed, but I was hoping someone could help and provide a less-cumbersome method.

Thanks.

**Update 1**

using regex (@user2864740)

```
^(?:\s{4})*\s{1,3}\S
```

or (@alpha bravo)

```
^(?!(\s{4})+\S)(.*)
```

matches non-multiple-of-4 indents, as well as empty line(s) with 4 (8, 16, etc.) spaces and the first character of the first non-empty line following them.

[e.g.](http://regex101.com/r/kJ3zF0/1) (on regex101.com)

How to avoid matching these situations described in the example above?

Comment: `^(?!\s{16}|\s{12}|\s{8}|\s{4}).*`

Comment: use vim, `:set shiftround`, `gg>G<G`, `:wq`, done

Comment: @Eevee And that is why I've never really tried to learn vim D:

Comment: @hjpotter92 this one matches things I described AND line start with a non-space character, as well as empty line

Comment: @user2864740 you can't tell me that makes _less_ sense than the regular expressions in the question and answers  :)  (it indents the entire file one level, then unindents.  `shiftround` forces indentation commands to always indent to a multiple of the tab stop, even if the line was misaligned before.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A character class can only contain .. a set of characters, and thus `[^..]` is not suitable for a general negation. The regular expression `[^( {16}| {12}| {8}| {4})]` is equivalent to `[^( {16}|284]` which would match every *character* not listed.

Now, to match *not* a multiple of 4 spaces is the same as finding `n mod 4 = {1, 2, 3}` (or anything *except* `n mod 4 = 0`) spaces. This can be done with a pattern such as the following:

```
(?:\s{4})*\s{1,3}\S
```

Explanation:

```
(?:\s{4})*  - match any number of whole groups of 4 spaces and then ..
\s{1,3}     - match any count of 1, 2, or 3 spaces such that ..
\S          - they are not followed by a space
```

The regular expression may need a trailing dot-all (`.*`) or leading line-anchor (`^`), depending on how it is used.

Comment: Matches what I described. Also match empty line(s) and the first character of the first non-empty line following it. See **Update 1** in post for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I could offer a python script that'll tell you which lines are improperly indented:

```
with open('path/to/code/file') as infile:
    for i,line in enumerate(infile,1):
        total = len(line)
        whitespace = total-len(line.lstrip(' '))
        if whitespace%4:
            print("Inconsistent indenting on line", i)
```

Comment: I admire the pure regexp solution of @user2864740, but regexps are often used as the end-all-be-all of string matching. This lstrip-based solution is short, sweet, and very understandable. A true regexp-based solution is inherently more complicated.

Comment: True that Python can do this much more straight forward. However I'm think this is a bit of overkill since I can do "Find" with a single line of regex (as long as script itself doesn't have too much matches). But thank you for providing this.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this pattern`^(?!(\s{4})+\S)(.*)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW0nX9/1)

Comment: Cool. Remember to add a little explanation. Also, I believe `(\s{4})*` may be more appropriate so that `no_ident = foo` won't be matched.